# Startup script on Debian 8 (Jessie) with etherwake won't work

Tags: shell-script, debian, startup, wake-on-lan

I'm attempting to remotely wake a slave machine when the master boots up through a bash script using the `etherwake` command to send magic packets. Both OSs are Debian 8. The full code is written below:

### /etc/init.d/etherwake

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/init.d/etherwake

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: etherwake
# Required-Start: $all
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start etherwake at boot time
# Description: Enable service provided by etherwake.
### END INIT INFO

ETHERWAKE=/usr/sbin/etherwake

case "$1" in

        start)
                echo  "Booting slaves through etherwake..."
                $ETHERWAKE <MAC Address>
                echo  "Finished booting all slaves."
                ;;

        stop)
                echo "Stop not implemented. Doing nothing"
                ;;

        restart|force-reload)
                $0 stop
                sleep 10
                $0 start
                ;;

        *)
                echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/etherwake {start}"
                exit 1
                ;;
esac

exit 0
```

After writing the script, I did:

1. `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/etherwake`
2. `update-rc.d etherwake defaults`
3. Reboot the system through `shutdown -r now`

I've also tried using `/etc/rc.local` in 3 different ways:

### /etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local

/etc/init.d/etherwake
etherwake <MAC Address>
/usr/sbin/etherwake <MAC Address>
exit 0
```

No luck whatsoever. When I run either `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/init.d/etherwake` manually as root, everything works nicely. I thought it could be something with the permissions but as far as I read any script on `/etc/init.d` runs as root by default. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---

### Edit:

I understand Debian 8 uses systemd instead of sysvinit. After setting everything up`systemctl -l status etherwake.service` gives me:

```
● etherwake.service - Etherwake magic packet service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/etherwake.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2016-09-30 16:30:56 BRT; 1min 33s ago
  Process: 824 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/etherwake start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 824 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 30 16:30:56 hostname etherwake[824]: Booting slaves through etherwake...
Sep 30 16:30:56 hostname etherwake[824]: Finished booting all slaves.
```

And `/etc/systemd/system/etherwake.service` is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Etherwake magic packet service
Wants=network-online.target
After=syslog.service network.target network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/etherwake start

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Another thing I noticed is that running `systemctl restart etherwake` works as a charm.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the output of `systemctl -l status etherwake.service`?

Comment: Done. @StevenMonday

Comment: I'd *guess* your unit is somehow being run before the network is really up. You might be able to tell from the full log (e.g., `journalctl -b`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `update-rc.d etherwake defaults` maybe don't work. Try to enable service via `systemctl`, run:

```
systemctl enable etherwake
```